# ideal iterations for neural network training

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network

I've designed MLP network and training it using a dataset that has 10000 inputs, each input has 5 dimensions and I expect 1 output. Is there a formula to calculate the ideal iterations needed for N number of inputs.

Comment: Need more detail and any code you have used to implement .. or else there will be a chance to get downvote ...

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan I don't need help with coding. Thus no need to share it. The problem is simple and as much detail as possible is provided. MLP network is trained, 10000 training data is available, each have 5 dimensions and 1 output is expected. What would be the ideal iterations for the training? That's all. There might be a formula used for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no generic formula as such to determine no. of iterations for a given training dataset.

No. of iterations is just one of the parameters which affect the classifier. Other hyperparameters include no. of layers and no. of neurons in each layer and learning rate.

You can do hyperparameter tuning and check at what point the classifier is overfitting. You can start with small no. of iterations and see at which point adding further iterations is not helping in decreasing the error.